# Cannot convert type string to decimal in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have my linq query where I'm joining 3 tables. grouping them into another so I can sum values in table 3

```
var roles = from p in db.Properties 
                    join od in db.tblOrderDetails on p.pID equals od.odpID 
                    join s in db.tblServices on od.odsID equals s.sID                        
                    where p.poID == 0 && p.pActive == true   

                    group s by new {p.pID, p.pAddress} into g
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = g.Key.pID,
                        Address = g.Key.pAddress,
                        SubTotal = g.Sum(s => s.sPrice)
                    };
```

My problem comes in at the SubtTotal.
I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal?'"
I tried using convert.todecimal but I get

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal
>   ToDecimal(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

sqlfunctions.stringconvert doesn't help either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting to decimal ie (decimal)

Comment: you need to explicitly cast the s.sPrice to a nullable decimal so the lambda will see it properly.

Comment: Your problem is that you have a `sPrice` that is a string... Perhaps you have another `*Price` that is a number. It is quite strange to save only a string for a price on the db

Comment: I believe it's a limitation in the provider, because it is parsing your query into an expression that can be evaluated in the database, and Convert.ToDecimal() isn't recognized in the database expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think this conversion from LINQ to Entitites to LINQ to Objects could be used if the data volume is considerably small:

```
  var roles = (from p in db.Properties 
         join od in db.tblOrderDetails on p.pID equals od.odpID 
         join s in db.tblServices on od.odsID equals s.sID                        
         where p.poID == 0 && p.pActive == true   

         group s by new {p.pID, p.pAddress} into g)
           .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new
                {
                    ID = p.Key.pID,
                    Address = p.Key.pAddress,
                    SubTotal = p.Sum(s => s.sPrice)
                });
```